# How to "undo changes" on a mongoose document?

Tags: node.js, testing, mongoose, mocha.js

I need to undo changes in my mongoose-loaded document for testing purposes.

Ie. I try setting something to wrong type, and of course, fail. then I try something else, but I fail on the first error. Example:

```
// here I load the user
before(function(done) {
  user = loadUserSomehow();
  done();
})
it ('should validate email', function(done) {

    // now I try one field wrong
    user.email = 'This is not a valid email';
    user.save(function(err) {
        err.message.should.equal.'Invalid email'; // to simplify
        // I would get 'invalid email' error here.
    });
});
it ('should validate type', function(done) {

    // now I try another field wrong
    user.type = 'This type does not exist';
    user.save(function(err) {
        err.message.should.equal.'Invalid user type'; // THIS fails
        // instead of invalid type, I still get an invalid email message
    });
});
```

To avoid having to reload the doc before every test, how do I "undo the changes" on a mongoose document?

Comment: As a side note, you aren't calling `done()` in your tests

Comment: I you found better solutions, It'd be great if you could answer your own question so other people can benefit from your research. Thanks

Comment: I think I went with some mock db setup. It was such a long time ago so I honestly don't remember.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose doesn't support "undoing" that. However, you can have multiple options:

1. Handle the undoing manually. If you run all tests in sequence, you can edit your tests so they look like:

   ```
   it ('should validate email', function(done) {
       var oldValue = user.email;
       user.email = 'This is not a valid email';
       user.save(function(err) {
           err.message.should.equal.'Invalid email';
           user.email = oldValue;
           done(null);
       });
   });
   ```

   Note that this is not a proper "undoing", as Mongoose will still consider `user.email` as modified (if you run `user.isModified('email')` you should get  a true value).
2. Just go ahead re-loading `user` before every test. Since this is not a production environment, but just a test case, optimizing here shouldn't be too important. Just change the name of your `before` method to `beforeEach`

Answer (score 0):

You could point the created documents to some vars (const) and run a deleteMany for every var after the test

```
const someDocument = undefined;

// it should ... your testing code
// point "new Document()" to someDocument

afterEach(async () => {
    Document.deleteMany({_id: someDocument._id});
})
```

---

You could also connecting to a different Database for testing and sending everything to dump on finish

Comment: Hi! This is a 5 year old question, I've long since moved on and found better solutions, but  thanks for your answer and contribution, it might give an idea to someone else googling into this question/answer.

Comment: I you found  better solutions, It'd be great if you could answer your own question so other people can benefit from your research. Thanks